# Ошибка java.util.InputMismatchException

Tags: java

Возникла ошибка java.util.InputMismatchException. Почитал в интернете что это вроде несоответствие типов, но я ввожу всё верно. Ошибка возникает только если вводить более 1 слова. Кто подскажет в чём ошибка? Если добавить in.nextLine() который ни на что не ссылается после h1.name = in.next(), то всё работает правильно, но мне интересно почему без него ничего не работает..?

```
  package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InputMismatchException {
        Human h1 = new Human();
        Cat c1 = new Cat();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Введите имя владельца: ");
        h1.name = in.next();
        //in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Введите возраст владельца: ");
        h1.age = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Введите город проживания владельца: ");
        h1.town = in.next();
        System.out.println("Информация о хозяине: ");
        System.out.println("Имя: "+h1.name);
        System.out.println("Возраст: "+h1.age);
        System.out.println("Город проживания: "+h1.town);
    }
}
```

h1.name это переменная типа String.

Answer (score 1):

Это потому, что `next()` захватывает только следующий токен, а пробел выступает в качестве разделителя между токенами. И когда вы вводите 2 слова - считывается только первое. А второе считывается методом `nextInt()`. 
Я так примаю ошибка на строке `h1.age = in.nextInt().`

Поменяйте `h1.name = in.next();` на `h1.name = in.nextLine();` и все будет хорошо

Comment: но тогда имя будет состоять из строки, а мне нужно чтобы имя состояло из 1 слова.

Comment: Так если надо чтобы состояло из одного слова, то надо вводить одно слово. Ошибка возникает только при вводе 2 слов. С таким же успехом можно возраст ввести "20 лет" и тоже будет ошибка.

Comment: Тогда по хорошему нужны проверки перед присваиванием hasNextInt()